# Splitting a range provided in a row into several smaller ranges in multiple rows

Tags: r

I am somehow new to programming and I have been struggling to have my desirable output as explained below.

Suppose i have a table like table below:
[My input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wxyY.jpg)

which includes the range of coordinates (Start_MP & End_MP) of a specific segment (defied by ID) and length of the segment (difference between the range start and end). 
What I need to do is, to split all those ranges which have a length of more than 2, into ranges of two or less. To make it more clear I need my output to be like table below
[My desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xM7sm.jpg)

I would appreciate if you let me know how I can handle that with R/ R packages?

Comment: Could you please provide data frames? It will be easier for others to provide answer if data is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `tidyr::expand` is the right option to use to expand rows based on choice/desire of OP.

Approach is to first use `expand` to generate desired number of rows and then use `left_join` to join those with original data.frame.

```
# Data
df <- data.frame(Segment_ID = c(1101, 1102, 1103), Start_MP = c(1, 5, 20),
                  End_MP = c(2, 10, 30), Segment_Length = c(1, 5, 10))

library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(Segment_ID) %>% 
  expand(Segment_ID, Segment_Sequence_Number = 
                seq(from = Start_MP, to = End_MP, by = 2)) %>%
  left_join(df, by="Segment_ID") %>%
  mutate(Start_MP = Segment_Sequence_Number) %>%
  group_by(Segment_ID) %>%
  mutate(End_MP_Calc = lead(Start_MP)) %>%
  mutate(End_MP = coalesce(End_MP_Calc, End_MP)) %>% 
  filter(Start_MP != End_MP) %>%
  mutate(Segment_Length = End_MP - Start_MP) %>%
  group_by(Segment_ID) %>%
  mutate(Segment_Sequence_Number = row_number()) %>%
  select(-End_MP_Calc) %>% as.data.frame()

#Result
#   Segment_ID Segment_Sequence_Number Start_MP End_MP Segment_Length
# 1       1101                       1        1      2              1
# 2       1102                       1        5      7              2
# 3       1102                       2        7      9              2
# 4       1102                       3        9     10              1
# 5       1103                       1       20     22              2
# 6       1103                       2       22     24              2
# 7       1103                       3       24     26              2
# 8       1103                       4       26     28              2
# 9       1103                       5       28     30              2
```

Comment: Thank a lot MKR. When I run your code it gives me the following error:
Error in rank(x, ties.method = "first", na.last = "keep") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default.

also when I run it on a bigger sample it stops in the meanwhile and gives me this error:
r in seq.default(from =Start_MP, to = End_MP,  : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument
Any suggestion on how to edit it?

Comment: @F.gh First try to run it on the toy data.frame provided with answer. (I created it based on your input). I think in your real data.frame few rows got `End_MP` less than `Start_MP`. You can tidy those rows first.